# i want to seach using id and name in the same time in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

in the data base i have a object like this

---

```
{
 "examid": "60901056c2a9282e28b4c85b",
 "user":"608ac758527bbcc8d834e23e",
"answers":["array"]}
```

---

how can i do something like this in MongoDB

---

`SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE EXAMID=1 AND USER=test`

i try

`test.find({$elemMatch:{examid:1,user:test}})`

---

but i got a err "unknown top level operator"

Comment: see [$and conditional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/), or simply just try `.find({ examId: 1, user: test })`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
test.find({
  "examid": 1,
  "user": test
})
```

Here is the working snippet: https://mongoplayground.net/p/oPuyrlDMYVJ